C# Incrementing Interval
I'm trying to achieve an interval the increments with each step. If the initial interval is 30 and the increment level is 1: the next interval is 31, then 32, 33...
int ii = 1800
int ib = 60

private void generateGridBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        TimeSpan iiTS = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ii);
        DateTime nextDT = DateTime.Now.Add(iiTS);
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = nextDT.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        ii = ii + ib;
    }
}

This is a for loop that starts with two integers, one for the interval, and one for the increment, but it doesn't produce the desired results. It only adds one number. There is no increase.

This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with using a debugger.  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Your for-loop already comes with everything you need: for(int i = 1800; i < 61800; i+=60). Just start with the desired inital value and increment by the desired value.

It looks like you wanted to make the next:
private void generateGridBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    DateTime nextDT = DateTime.Now;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        TimeSpan iiTS = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ii);
        nextDT = nextDT.Add(iiTS);
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = nextDT.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        ii = ii + ib;
    }
}

nextDT is the timestamp to increase on each cycle step.
To optimize:
private void generateGridBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    DateTime nextDT = DateTime.Now;
    int lim = ii + 1000 * ib;
    for (int i = ii; i < lim; i += ib)
    {
        nextDT = nextDT.AddSeconds(i);
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = nextDT.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    }
}

